# ImageMagick vs GraphicMagick: How to move image

Tags: imagemagick, image-manipulation, graphicmagick

So, I have a bunch of files that I use as the basis for my wallpapers. Using [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org), I can convert then using:

```
convert \
    -resize '1920x1080>' \
    -extent 1920x1080 \
    -background '#000000' \
    -gravity SouthEast \
    $file $dir/$file
```

So that the image is moved to the lower right area of the screen. This area has little or no windows thus I can actually see the wallpapper. The reason I do this is that some of the images are bigger than my monitor and thus need rescaling instead of just putting there.
However, using [GraphicMagick](http://www.graphicsmagick.org) with the above command, results in the image being moved towards the upper right corner!

*How can I achieve a similar effect with [GraphicMagick](http://www.graphicsmagick.org)?*

For an example, this is one of the post processed images:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`extent` must be used [after](http://www.graphicsmagick.org/GraphicsMagick.html#details-extent) `background` and `gravity`, e.g.:

```
gm convert -resize '1920x1080>' -background black -gravity SouthEast -extent 1920x1080 infile outfile
```

or

```
gm convert infile -resize '1920x1080>' -background black -gravity SouthEast -extent 1920x1080 outfile
```